# Can an employer force an employee to have a social media account and put their current employment information on the profile?

Tags: united-states, employment, florida, social-media

A person I know recently received some new rules from their employer regarding expected social media behavior, which they need to sign. Before signing, I started reading it, and the last point mentioned was that the employee must have at least one social media account with the job title and description information on their profile, or the could face disciplinary action.What if the employee does not have a social media account, or simply does not want/care to put their employment information on social media?

Can an employer force an employee to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't find any law that would prevent an employer from requiring this.  Under current Florida law, an employer can even demand passwords and access to an employee's social media accounts.  A [bill was proposed](http://www.flsenate.gov/Session/Bill/2016/0186/?Tab=RelatedBills) to prohibit this, but it hasn't passed.

Generally, an employer can require anything they want as a condition of employment, as long as it is not illegal.  Florida has [at-will employment](https://www.myfloridalaw.com/employee-laws-in-florida/) so the employer could certainly fire the employee if they don't comply.